# German-English word frequency list (1000-5000)

Tags: learning

I am not looking just for German words frequency list, for which there are many in this site and others. But I am looking for translated German words frequency list.

Copy pasting from sites like memrise, creates all kinds of formatting problems.

So I was wondering if anyone has made such a list eg. anything about 1000 words.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that a translated list makes much sense since most of the german words (if not all) can be translated to much more then just one english word (and vice versa). How would you translate "Leiter" into english? Leader? Conductor? Ladder? Chief? I guess there are about 15 valid translations for this word.

Answer (score 2):

I did write it as a comment before: I don't think that a translated list makes much sense since most of the German words (if not all) can be translated to much more then just one English word (and vice versa).

See, what I mean:

These are the top 10 from the original list of the most frequent words in written German (spoken words are not counted):

> 1. der
> 2. die
> 3. und
> 4. in
> 5. den
> 6. von
> 7. zu
> 8. das
> 9. mit
> 10. sich

and this is the translated top-10-list:

> 1. the, which, who, that, he
> 2. the, which, who, that, her, she
> 3. and, plus
> 4. in, into, to, at, inside, thru, trendy
> 5. the, which, that one
> 6. of, from, by, out of, about
> 7. to, for, at, in, with, into, as, toward, towards
> 8. the, that, this, it, who
> 9. with, by, at, in, including, starring
> 10. yourself, itself, themselves, oneself, himself, herself, self, to himself, yourselves, to itself, to herself, to yourself, to oneself, to yourselves

So, how does this list help you?
At position 10 you find 14 different valid translations of "sich", where 6 of them consist of two words each. And among the top 10 you find the word "the" at 4 positions. Within the top 5000 you will find "turn" at 35 different positions.